# Error in XML file. Android programming

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and recently installed Eclipse junos and ADT plugin on my ubuntu system and downloaded the android SDK. After this, i created an android project, which by default is the hello world program, when i run this program i got an error "Error in an XML file: aborting build.". But i haven't edited any code. Please help me solve this problem.
Below is the program.
I get an error also saying R cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
package com.example.myandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:text="@string/hello_world" 
            tools:context=".MainActivity" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Send your XML file activity_main.

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Could you post it in the question (edit the question)? THat would make it a bit more readable :)

Comment: edit (add one extra space in last or first line) MainActivity.java and execute again.

Comment: To get rid of the "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error try using "import com.example.myandroid.R"

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: No. it did not work. Got an error stating " The import com.example.myandroid.R cannot be resolved" .

Comment: Ok. Are you able to get rid of the XML error now? See my updated answer on that. Once you are able to get rid of that the R issue can be sorted.

Comment: No. I tried your updated code. It did not work. Is their any other problem? I am using ubuntu, are there any other settings to configure?

Comment: The error is showing in activity_main.out XML file. But there is no code if i open it.

Comment: why don't you delete this xml and create new one

Comment: Deleted it. I also gone through the post you provided. But there is still error in mainActivity.java file. No XML error now.

Comment: You must not import R.java. R.java is generated during the build process. There are many questions on SO about this  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11139987/1689695

Comment: When your XML is correct, you clean your project, and then R.java will be generated in the gen directory. Also check your manifest file that there are no unresolved references eg to icons

Comment: no.. its not working even after i went through the post and changed as required.

Comment: Do you see the file R.java in your gen folder under com.example.myandroid package?

Comment: [2012-10-23 15:33:04 - adb] Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/vinuthan/Documents/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory from '/home/vinuthan/Documents/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb' - exists=true

Comment: I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools";
```

the semicolon above seems to be the problem try and remove them

Comment: No, that did not help either.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048988/eclipse-3-7-android-r-java-missing) My problem is exactly like this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
                android:text="@string/hello_world" 
                tools:context=".MainActivity" /> 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

You have extra semi colons in your xml file.

Also make sure the first line of your xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

So your complete xml should look like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        tools:context=".MainActivity" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse for developement?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your java file, however your updated xml still has the extra semi colons (;) you need to remove those.

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse Juno in ubuntu with Open JDK java.

Comment: You might want to clear your xml and try and use the code that I have provided. See if that helps.

Comment: I have updated my XML file now. I also used your code. But still get the same error. Is there any other problem.

Comment: Are there any other settings to be done if i use ubuntu OS for programming?. Is that a problem?

Comment: try to clean your project and then run

Comment: The error is showing in activity_main.out XML file. But there is no code if i open it.

Comment: why don't you delete this xml and re-create new one?

Comment: @13hsoj any of my xml doesn't have this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` line as first line.

Comment: Deleted it. I also gone through the post you provided. But there is still error in mainActivity.java file. No XML error now.

Comment: To get rid of the "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error try using "import com.example.myandroid.R"